# How to input entire sentence and print it until certain character?

Tags: c

How to input a sentence and print it until a certain character?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int T;//testcase
    char str[1001];
    int i;

    scanf("%d",&T);
    getchar();
    for(int t=1; t<=T; t++){
        for(i=0; i!='\n';i++){
            scanf("%c",str[i]);
            getchar();
        }

        for(i=0; i!='\n'; i++){
            if(str[i]=='f' || str[i]=='F'){
                break;
            }else{
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input is alphanumeric sentence.
The output will be the sentence if there is no 'f' or 'F'.
The output will be the sentence until the 'f' or 'F'.

**Example:**

> input: Hello world
>   output: Hello world
>
> input: Chocolate Truffle
>   output: Chocolate Tru

Comment: What's wrong with just using **getchar** and **putchar** in a loop until you see `f`, `F` or newline?

Comment: Where in the code are you printing the output?

Comment: Comparing `i!='\n'` is certainly wrong when you use `i` as an array index for `str[i]` You could compare `str[i]` with `'\n'` after reading it and before incrementing `i`. The combination of `scanf("%c",...)` with `getchar()` is wrong when you want to read a line of input. This might be useful only if you want to input a single character followed by ENTER. I suggest to add comments what you think the code should do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int nbOfTests;               // use a self explaining name rather than "T"
  char str[1001];

  scanf("%d", &nbOfTests);
  getchar();   // absorb \n

  for (int t = 1; t <= nbOfTests; t++) {
    for (i = 0; ; i++) {
      str[i] = getchar();     // no scanf needed, just use `getchar`directly
      if (str[i] == '\n')
        break;                // Enter = > end the loop
    }

    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {  // declare i here
      if (str[i] == 'f' || str[i] == 'F' || str[i] == '\n')
        break;                // f F or Enter => end the loop
      else
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");             // makes it more readable for the user
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: this code is still pretty poor, but close to the original code, for example it would be better and simpler to use `fgets` to read a line of text.